# Espresso - preform click on item inside RecyclerView that has specified text

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have a RecyclerView with items that represent available slots. Let's assume that those slots represent theatre spectacles. Every slot has a number ***n*** of available tickets and can be either in **OPEN** or **CLOSED** state. If a slot is **OPEN**, it contains a `TextView` with text OPEN and I can click on it and I will be redirected to **Buy Ticket Flow**. Otherwise, if my slot is CLOSED, it becomes disabled and I cannot click on it (with text CLOSED on `TextView`)

How can I test following scenario:

1. select any slot from the RecyclerView that has a OPEN slot
2. perform click
3. verify that I have been redirected to **Buy Ticket Flow**

I have tried using:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(
      RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(10, click()) // <-- only position
);
```

I still don't know how to pick a slot based on it's content instead of position. I have found something about `actionOnItem()` but cannot figure out how it works yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `actionOnItem()`.

There are two things you'll need in order to get `actionOnItem()` to work.

1. The resource id of the recyclerview. Looks like you already have that with`R.id.recycler_view`
2. The specific Type of `ViewHolder` that you wish to `perform` a `ViewAction` on (such as `click()`). You should be able to find this wherever you defined your RecyclerView in your app code

Once you have these two things, you can tell Espresso to first find the recyclerview, and then scan the viewholders within it to match whatever matcher you pass in.

**Example:**

```
// Step 1: Tell espresso which RecyclerView we're working with
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    // Step 2: Tell espresso which ViewHolder Type to look for inside the RecyclerView
    .perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem<TheaterSpectacleAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        // Step 3: Using a ViewMatcher, tell espresso what viewholder you want to act on
            ViewMatchers.withText("OPEN"),
            // Step 4: using a ViewAction, tell Espresso what you want to do with this ViewHolder
            ViewActions.click()
        )
    )
```

I can't remember off the top of my head, but you might get a MultipleMatchingViewInHierarchy exception, since there are multiple items of your ViewHolder type matching `withText("OPEN")` If that's the case, try using this custom "first" matcher, which should just grab you the first View that espresso matches on

```
        /**
         * Find the first displayed view that matches the [matcher]
         * @param matcher: the matcher used to find the desired view
         */
        fun <View> first(matcher: Matcher<View>): Matcher<View> {
            return object : BaseMatcher<View>() {
                var isFirst = true
                override fun matches(item: Any): Boolean {
                    if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item)) {
                        isFirst = false
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }

                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    description.appendText("the first $matcher")
                }
            }
        }
```

and use it like so

```
            // Step 3: Using a ViewMatcher, tell espresso what viewholder you want to act on
            first(ViewMatchers.withText("OPEN")),
```

Lol actually... come to think of it... since your particular test scenario is "Pick **any** slot that says OPEN"... you could probably get away with running

```
onView(first(withText("OPEN")).perform(click())
```

However if the test gets more complicated, you'll enjoy the flexibility of being able to be more specific regarding which ViewHolders you want to use.

Hopefully one of these two answers works!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for clicking TextView with "OPEN"

```
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view), isDisplayed()))
            .perform(actionOnItem(withChild(withText("OPEN")), click()));
```

Assuming **Buy Ticket Flow** is a new activity, check if intent is fired

```
intended(hasComponent(Buy_Ticket_Flow.class.getName()));
```