# How to click Recyclerview position with specific View Visible- Espresso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-testing, gui-testing

I am writing UI Test for my App using Espresso. The screen shows a `Recyclerview` with list of shops that have status `OPEN` or `CLOSED`. Depending upon the data the `openTextView` or `closedTextview` is shown and are hidden by default.

**Below is my test case scenario:**

- Check if screen is visible
- Check if Recyclerview is visible
- Check if Recyclerview has atleast one shop with `OPEN` status
- Click on first found `OPEN` shop
- Check if details screen shows up

**ISSUE:**

I tried to click the first `OPEN` status item but it is throwing Exception.

Below is the code

```
@Test
fun openShopTest() {

    onView(withText(“Shops")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

    onView(withId(R.id.rvShops)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

    //There is at least one open shop visible

    onView(withId(R.id.rvShops))
        .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToHolder(first(withOpenText())))

    //User clicks on open shop

    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.rvShops), isDisplayed()))
        .perform(actionOnItem<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder>(withChild(withText(“Open”)), click()))

    //Screen with details appear

    onView(withText("Details”)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

}

fun withOpenText(): Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    return object :
        BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, ListAdapter.ListViewHolder>(
            ListAdapter.ListViewHolder::class.java
        ) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("No ViewHolder found with Open Status Visible")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(item: ListAdapter.ListViewHolder): Boolean {
            val openTextView = item.itemView.findViewById(R.id.openTextView) as TextView
            return openTextView.isVisible
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the exception:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'performing ViewAction: single click on item matching: holder with view: has child: with text: is "Open"' on view '(with id: mypackagename:id/rvShops and is displayed on the screen to the user)'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
at mypackagename.MyUITest.openShopTest(MyUITest.kt:77)
... 32 trimmed
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has child: with text: is "Open"' on view 'RecyclerView{id=2131231032, res-name=rvShops, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2047, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@295fec9, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=12}'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:381)
at androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:221)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found 0 items matching holder with view: has child: with text: is "Open", but position -1 was requested.
at androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:361)
```

**What i have tried?**

- I had an idea that maybe `openTextView` or `closedTextview` are not always visible so that might be causing the problem. I tried by making both always visible as well.
- I followed the steps mentioned in answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600556/espresso-preform-click-on-item-inside-recyclerview-that-has-specified-text) but the same excpetion shows up.

**What is required?**

- Click on Recyclerview row where `openTextView` is visible
- Get position of row where `openTextView` is visible; so that i can use `atPosition` function and click the row.

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there is possible to recyclerview is not visible? if not I think you can check by simple method like ` onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Open"))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to custom the View action of Espresso.

```
object MyViewAction {
    fun clickChildViewWithIdAndText(id: Int, text: String): ViewAction {
        return object: ViewAction {
            override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
                return withText(text)
            }

            override fun getDescription(): String {
                return "Click on a child view with specified id and text"
            }

            override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View) {
                val v: View = view.findViewById(id)
                v.performClick()
            }
        }
    }
}

onView(withId(R.id.rv_home)).perform(
      RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder>(
          0,
          MyViewAction.clickChildViewWithIdAndText(R.id.tv_id, "OPEN")
      )
);
```

By the way, you can use some powerful testing libraries which are built on top of Espresso such as [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista) or [Kakao](https://github.com/KakaoCup/Kakao). It helps your testing code to be much more readable and elegant.

For example, you can assert the item displayed at position x with text y in the list view with just one line of code

```
import com.adevinta.android.barista.assertion.BaristaListAssertions.assertDisplayedAtPosition

assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.rv_list, x, R.id.tv_id, y)
```